# How to zoom in on a unctacked matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot an unscattered bar chart of about 268 entires, in python, however, I'm having issues with scaling of the graph

Here's my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(first)
first_class = df.iloc[:,2].to_list()
second_upper = df.iloc[:,3].to_list()
second_lower = df.iloc[:,4].to_list()
third_class = df.iloc[:,5].to_list()


barWidth = 2
r1 = np.arange(len(first_class))
r2 = [x + barWidth for x in r1]
r3 = [x + barWidth for x in r2]
r4 = [x + barWidth for x in r3]


plt.bar(r1, first_class, color='#7f6d5f', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='first')
plt.bar(r2, second_upper, color='#557f2d', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='second_up')
plt.bar(r3, second_lower, color='#2d7f5e', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='second_low')
plt.bar(r4, third_class, color='#2d7f5e', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='third')


plt.xlabel('group', fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(first_class))])
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=20)


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and this is the output I'm getting :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/baKY5.png

Comment: hm, why don't you just do `df.iloc[:,2:6].plot.bar()`?